# Appending textarea data on pressing Enter key to a comment post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating a commenting system whose structure is like below:

```
<div id="main_comment_DIV_id_no">
     //Some user comment
</div>
<div "reply_DIV">
    <textarea name="reply_comment" id="reply_comment" rows="1" style="width:100%">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

I want to append the textarea data to the main comment (also updating the database) part on pressing the `Enter` key.

I can easily accomplish this if there is only one (or few) `DIV`s, but here I have `n` numbers of `DIV`s so I am searching for a solution to append the nth reply data to the nth `main_comment_DIV` only.

Any help will be highly useful?

Comment: What did you try here?

Comment: Add your code... we can try to debug it. But creating it is entirely your task.

Comment: @Ronak and j809 thanks for the comment,I just want to know logic I should apply here....I tried to run my mind but got no luck

Comment: What element has focus when you press enter?

Comment: @user3803005: So, you want to use ajax? When you click on enter all old and new message should come in main container. right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic. That might help you.
When you click on enter, call ajax function and pass reply_comment with it. In php side, add that comment into the database and fetch all messages from database. On ajax success,

```
$('#main_messages_container').html(null);
$('#main_messages_container').html(res);
```

This will give you all updated messages with the new one. You don't need to append any div container in this case.

DETAILED ANSWER:

```
$('#enter_key_button').on('click',function(){
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: {textarea : textarea},
        success: function (res) {
            //alert(res);
            $('#main_messages_container').html(null);
            $('#main_messages_container').html(res);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the keyup event and jquery class selector. You should not use id as selector, because you said you have n number of main comment dive, so id of n number of divs should not be same.

```
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[name="reply_comment"]').keyup(function(e){
                if(e.which === 13){
                    var comment = $(e.currentTarget).val(),
                    commentDiv = $('.main_comment_DIV_id_no');
                    //you have the comment here, so you can call an ajax request to update it in the database.
                       $(e.currentTarget).val("");
                     //if the blank div where you want to add the comment is already present, then write
                      $(commentDiv[commentDiv.length-1]).text(comment);
                 // Else no need to add the blank div initially, just create a new div and add the comment there.
                  $(commentDiv[commentDiv.length-1]).after('<div class="main_comment_DIV_id_no">'+comment+'</div>');
                }

            })

        })

    </script>
    <div class="main_comment_DIV_id_no">
        Some user comment
    </div>
    <div class="main_comment_DIV_id_no">
        Some user comment2
    </div>
    <div class="main_comment_DIV_id_no">

    </div>
    <div id="reply_DIV">
        <textarea name="reply_comment" id="reply_comment"   rows="1"  style="width:100%" ></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
```